# Acrobat 7 stalls downloading PDF from IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, adobe-acrobat

I have a large (6mb) PDF file which is static content on an IIS web site. If the web site is on IIS7 (windows server 2008 r2 64-bit) and the user is using Acrobat 7, the download stalls and acrobat hangs, sometimes with an error saying the file could not be read.

This happens for different files, different browsers, and different hardware. However, it is specific to the combination of IIS7 and Acrobat 7; if I use acrobat 9 everything is fine, and likewise if I move the web site to a windows 2003 (IIS6) box.

Does anyone have any clues as to what could be causing it or if there are any settings I can change within IIS to fix this problem.

Thanks

Andy

Comment: I have now verified the same behaviour with another windows 2008 server installation and also the same problem happens with Acrobat 8

Answer (score 2):

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/807/cpsid_80780.html

Edit: Which links to Microsoft KB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979543/en-us

You cannot open some IIS 7.5-hosted PDF documents by using a Web browser that has the Adobe PDF Reader plug-in enabled

Which I'd guess is probably included in WS2008 R2 SP1.